# Power Shell上で以下のようなMacコマンド&Rubyコマンドを実行したい

Tags: ruby, powershell

```
ruby -e "l = STDIN.readlines; 10000.times{print l.sample}" < **file_name.csv** | wc -l
```

これをPower Shell上で行おうとするとき、どのように記述するのがよいのでしょうか？

```
(Get-Content **file_name.csv** |ruby -e"l = STDIN.readlines; 10000.times{print l.sample};").Length
```

のように記述してみましたが、結果が出てきません。
初心者質問ですみません、ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご回答お願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

`ruby -e`と`"`の間にスペースが入っていないため、エラーとなるようです。

```
(Get-Content **file_name.csv** |ruby -e "l = STDIN.readlines; 10000.times{print l.sample};").Length
```